# Spring Boot and Jersey Static Content

Tags: spring-boot, jersey

I have configured spring boot to load Jersey as a filter.

spring.jersey.type=filter
I have set my Jersey property to allow static content:

property(ServletProperties.FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404, true);
I have read in spring boot that I can put my content inside my resources dir, under directories named 'static', 'public' folders. Yet, I can never reach my index.html page. The only way I have gotten this to work is to create a webapp dir under src/main and put my index.html file in there. I am deploying the app as a jar.

The problem occurs when there is a usage of exception jersey provider handler like:

```
package com.product.api.endpoint;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.product.api.entity.DefaultError;
import com.product.api.exception.DefaultException;

@Component 
@Provider
public class DefaultExceptionHandler  implements ExceptionMapper<RuntimeException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(RuntimeException ex) {

        if(ex instanceof DefaultException) {
            DefaultException dex = (DefaultException) ex;
            return Response.status(dex.getCode())
                            .entity(new DefaultError(dex.getMessage()))
                            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                            .build();
        } else {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                            .entity(new DefaultError(ex.getMessage()))
                            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                            .build();
        }


    }

}
```

If the @Provider it is not defined the static content works like a charm.

Comment: Have you followed the advice that you were [already given](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11657)? Your question suggests that you haven't.

Comment: Yes, for the spring version 1.4.0 does not work.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](/help/mcve) that shows it not working? It's not clear from your question how you have tried to get this to work.

Comment: I've understood the problem. It's not about the version, infact it's about using the @Provider as exception handler. Until now i did not found a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into exact the same issue, and I solved it by adding these lines:

```
public Response toResponse(RuntimeException exception) {
  if (exception.getMessage().equals("HTTP 404 Not Found")) {
    // allow ServletProperties.FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404 to work
    return Response.status(404).build(); // don't change content type or set entity
  }
  //...
}
```

Comment: This should be marked as the solution. Solved it for me.

Comment: superb.  It worked for me.